# Replace field with same type, but different meaning in Protocol Buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'd like to update a message in Protocol Buffers:

```
message Person {
    string name = 1;
}
```

Now, suppose that I don't want a `name` for a `Person`, but only its `address`:

```
message Person {
    string address = 1;
}
```

Now, the `id` could remain `1` since the type is always a string, but I was wondering if it's better to rewrite the message in this way:

```
message Person {
    string address = 2;

    reserved 1;
}
```

in order to have more readability between versions.

Answer (score -1):

you can just change the field name safely(if you want to keep same id and same type), please check below post would help you.

[Protocol buffer: does changing field name break the message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431685/protocol-buffer-does-changing-field-name-break-the-message)

and also in my opion it is always good have

```
 required or optional
```

annotation to the message fields

Comment: I wasn't talking about safety, I was talking about readability. I know that both versions have backward compatibility.

Comment: ah yes, forgot main point , yes using *reserved* will definitly add to readbility as well as protobuf compiler would flag if some one try to reuse it, though am not clear if you change "tag"(value 1 to 2)  message will be backward compatible as your old version program may not aware of this new value